# Can change an object(element) in an external component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want change area (element) when i call `changeArea` method on another component.

I want to like do this.

First, App.js

```
export default function App(props) {
    const [area, setArea] = React.useState(<><Button/><Button/></>)

    const changeArea = (element) => {
        setArea(element);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {<area/>}
            <ChildApp changeArea={changeArea}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And, ChildApp.js

```
export default function ChildApp(props) {

    // I want do call to change the area.
    props.changeArea(<></Select></>);
    …
}
```

Anyway this code is not working.

`Error`

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

> PS. It’s a simplification of the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling `props.changeArea(<></Select></>);` in the body of your component, so every time your component renders(function calls) you set the state of
parent(`App`), every update state in component cause to re-render(recall) the component and it's children, as a result you dealing with a loop, you `props.changeArea(<></Select></>);`, it cause to re-render it's parent, and re-render the parent cause to call `props.changeArea(<></Select></>);` You must not call in the body of your function directly, you can do it in `useEffect` or in some `eventHandler`. like this:

```
export default function ChildApp(props) {
  ...
  useEffect(()=> {
  props.changeArea(<></Select></>);
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

In the above code, `props.changeArea(<></Select></>);` calls first time `ChildApp` renders and in the other renders of `ChildApp` it never calls `props.changeArea`.

If you are looking to understand how you can do it in `eventHandler` you cand take a look to @Akhil solution.

Comment: Thanks! your solution is correct source code!!

Comment: You're weolcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
const ChildApp = (props) => {
  const buttonHandler = () => {
    props.changeArea(<h1>World</h1>)
  }
  return <><button onClick={buttonHandler}>Hello</button> </>
}

export default function App() {
  const [area, setArea] = React.useState(<><h1>Hello</h1></>)
    const changeArea = (element) => {
        setArea(element);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {area}
            <ChildApp changeArea={changeArea}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the method you suggested, I understood the concept.